# Converting an object to typed array object

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

Basically I have an object that I want to upload to S3. It's basically just a javascript Object like this:

```
Address1: "555 N Michigan Ave"
Address2: "5"
Birthday: "01/01/1990"
City: "Chicago"
Email: "test@test.com"
FirstName: "Test"
LastName: "test"
PatientType:"Has HemoA"
PhoneNumber: "(312) 555-5555"
SelectedGift: "Speaker"
SelectedUser: "Learn More"
State: "IL"
Zip: "60605"
```

When I use the variable holding this object as the `Body` I get an error when using `s3.putObject` as such:

`Error: Expected params.Body to be a string, Buffer, Stream, Blob, or typed array object`

I don't think my object is any one of these types though. How can I simply just upload this to a file in S3 that contains all the key/values?

Comment: You can't just convert an object to a typed array. Have you tried converting it to JSON and sending it as a string?

Comment: I have not, I will try that, thanks!